# How to return to another action within model and parameters in asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, url-parameters

From an action, is there anyway to return to another action within passing model and parameters?

I have tried this, but it's not working:

```
public ActionResult Action2()
{
   MyModel model = new MyModel();
   return View("Action1", new { model, param1 = "abc", param2 = "def" });
}
```

`Action1` and `Action2` are same Controller. I don't define `param1` and `param2` in `RouteConfig.cs`

I want it shows me like this in url: `/myController/Action1?param1=abc&param2=def`

I need to pass either `model` or parameters.

Can you tell me how to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Use

`return RedirectToAction("ActionName", new{p1=v1 , p2=v2 , ...});`

or if you want to pass whole of your model use:

`return RedirectToAction("ActionName", model);`

Comment: Thank you. But the answer cannot be applied to my project. Because that's a homepage which contains a `search`. After searching, I want it displays the `searched result` and references from `Action1 view`. Not `RedirectToAction`. Can you tell me more?

Comment: then search your item in Action2 (with HttpPost method) and return the View(results), not redirect nor other action.